# Create files with custom file permission in iOS apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, file-permissions

How I can set file permission to resource files which used by the application "programmatically or by any other settings in Xcode" , in iOS app development.

And also,

I need to know  how to restrict or grant access for the resource files or folders to other applications AND how to set READ_WRITE_EXECUTE permission for these files.

any references or  links will helpful for me

thanks in Advance .. :)

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? are you trying to restrict/grant other applications to use the resource or any other folders which are present in your application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem properly,

For security reason apple does not allow other applications to access your app related data like resources or folders as each app placed in its own sandbox. you can refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html)

Hope I answered your question.

**Edit :**
Go through [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation and make use of the API `setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` where you can set the attribute `NSFilePosixPermissions`.
I am not sure about this[not worked on this], you can give a try. looks like it will work.

Comment: @NithinCV If I answered your question correctly, please accept the answer as it may help others.

Comment: Thanks for your info, Is there any way to set READ_WRITE_EXECUTE file permission  for resource files inside an app itself programmatically or with any xcode settings.